# IF statement to select only titles that are not null in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jQuery and trying to figure how to use a simple `IF` statement in this code. I am trying to scrape the below website by extracting "title" and "link", and disregarding any "title" that is null because the extracted file had some null values for the "title". Basically, I do not want to return any "title" that is null. I appreciate your help.

```
var $ = context.jQuery;    
var result = [];

$(".inline").each( function() {
    result.push({
        title : $(this).find("a strong").text().trim(),      
        link : "https://www.kooora.com/" + $(this).find("a").attr("href"),
    });
});
  
return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
var $ = context.jQuery;    
var result = [];

$(".inline").each( function() {
    let title = $(this).find("a strong").text().trim();
    if(title.length > 0) {
        result.push({
            title : title,      
            link : "https://www.kooora.com/" + $(this).find("a").attr("href"),
        });
    }
});
  
return result;
```